# In the OAuth protocol, how does oauth_callback return the parameters behind #?

Tags: vue.js, oauth

Use the OAuth protocol to realize the single sign-on function of the project, but the project is redirected by the routing of vue, and the address after # is required to jump to the specified page, but the oauth_callback in the OAuth protocol seems to be unable to return the parameters after #.

I hope you guys can give me a solution if you have time, thank you guys in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code would be helpful.
I'll assume by 'redirected by the routing of vue' you mean you are using vue-router.
In your routes, you will specify paths which will require auth. Then, have middleware which supplies the auth or re-directs to a page where the authentication (login) can occur.
Is this callback the client's token? Try taking these interactions out of the URL.

Comment: I have thought of other solutions to this problem because of project differences, thank you for your answer.